# RailwayJS/Express on Railway: A true node.js alternative to Ruby On Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, coffeescript

From looking at the documentation of [RailwayJS](http://railwayjs.com/)/[Express On Railway](https://github.com/1602/express-on-railway) it seems like an elaborate NodeJS web–framework to me. It is built on top of ExpressJS, offers nice generators and scaffolding and has CoffeeScript support built right in. Does anyone have experience with this framework and would say that it is a true alternative to Ruby On Rails, Django or the like as Express is to Sinatra?

Comment: didn't know, seems really nice. +1 for sharing

Comment: Why would you want to :\ You don't need anything but express. The rest is bloat and forcing your into a box.

Comment: "Generators and scaffolding" are the least significant feature that Rails offers. If "generators and scaffolding" are the sum total of the similarity, then there is no similarity worth mentioning. (There may be a great similarity - if so, it's not because of "generators and scaffolding".)

Comment: @Raynos: isn't that what opinionated software is about?

Comment: @Justice: of course, I just said, it has nice generators and scaffolding built in, but that is not the reason for RailwayJS to be an alternative to Rails—right.

Comment: @ChristianTreppo maybe but its watering down the elegant and simplistic node with this unnecessary bloat. That's not how node works. Node is a sum of hand picked modules that do a single task very well the unix way. You don't want generic bloated systems with bad architecture.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As author of this project (railwayjs) I could tell you: sure, it's cool, use it, share it with colleagues, fork repo, and improve it. But as developer, how use this tool every day, I say to you: this is very young toolkit (less than 1 year old), it still needs more love than just use-out-of-box, as RoR, I not recommend to use it in production, if you are do not completely understand what happens in the app code.

So, if you want to have RoR replacement in nodejs in future - use it, and report about issues. It motivates me to make this project better.

Thanks for posting.

Comment: Great, thank you for your feedback! I like your railwaysjs and hope to be able to start some project with it soon.

Comment: I don't want to speak for Anatoliy; his words as of 4/3/12: I plan to have a vacation in nearest future and release 1.0 with freezed featureset. What should be done before 1.0:

- completely moved to ORM-independent state (almost done, just need to build some bridge module for mongoose as an example)
- refactored controller (done) and full documentation of other modules (almost done)
- tests (most important: controller, helpers)
- initialization API (hooks, more configurable initialization)
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/railwayjs/kJ128fTPaGw

Answer (score -12):

I don't know if the asynchronous nature of the Node environment will ever be quite as elegant as Ruby for Rails-like applications.

I say stick to what you're good at. At least until Node supports something like the Actor model to help with callback hell.

Comment: Meh there's flow control to handle callback hell. Just learn to write asynchronous code.